# How to Mock out a dependency Class in FastApi

Tags: mocking, pytest, fastapi

I have this endpoint:

```
from fastapi_limiter.depends import RateLimiter

@documents_router.delete(
    "/delete_document/{folder}/{file}",
    status_code=200,
    dependencies=[
        Depends(RateLimiter(times=1, seconds=10)),
        Depends(RateLimiter(times=2, hours=30)),
    ],
)
async def delete_document(
    folder: str,
    file: str,
    request: Request,
) -> dict:
    return dict(message="hello world!")
```

---

my test file

```
from fastapi_limiter.depends import RateLimiter
@pytest.fixture
async def test_client(mock_acquire):
    # https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/#using-testclient

    from app.main import app

    client = TestClient(app)

    app.dependency_overrides[RateLimiter] = lambda: Mock()

    return client
```

But I get the following error:

```
self = <fastapi_limiter.depends.RateLimiter object at 0x7fae1d318910>, 

    async def _check(self, key):
        redis = FastAPILimiter.redis
>       pexpire = await redis.evalsha(
            FastAPILimiter.lua_sha, 1, key, str(self.times), str(self.milliseconds)
        )
E       TypeError: object Mock can't be used in 'await' expression

../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi_limiter/depends.py:29: TypeError
```

I think I need to ensure that the instances of RateLimiter are also mocked (and every method is automatically mocked) - how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.8, you can use an [AsyncMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock) when trying to mock Asynchronous functionality. e.g.

```
from fastapi_limiter.depends import RateLimiter
from unittest.mock import AsyncMock

@pytest.fixture
async def test_client(mock_acquire):
    # https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/#using-testclient
    from app.main import app
    client = TestClient(app)
    rate_limiter_mock = AsyncMock(spec=RateLimiter)
    app.dependency_overrides[RateLimiter] = lambda: rate_limiter_mock
    return client
```

By using AsyncMock, the mock instance will be compatible with the async/await functionality. The spec argument ensures that the mock has the same attributes and methods as the original class.